# Firebause getCurrentUser().getEmail returns null

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

I developed an android application and in one of my activities, I give the user possibility to delete his account.

The deletion process does many things and at the **end** of the process, I delete the user itself.

I do it by using this:

```
new CountDownTimer( 7000, 500 ) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

        FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
        AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential( user.getEmail(), password );
        user.reauthenticate( credential ).addOnCompleteListener( task -> user.delete() );

        auth.signOut();

        AuthUI.getInstance()
                .signOut( context )
                .addOnCompleteListener( task -> {
                    Intent intent = new Intent( context, MainActivity.class );
                    intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
                            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
                    context.startActivity( intent );
                } );

        MainActivity.isDeleted = true;
    }

}.start();
```

However, I just got a log from one of the users where it says the app crashed due to:

```
 Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to read from field 'c.d.d.q.j0.i0 c.d.d.q.j0.l0.g' on a null object reference
com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzx.getEmail (zzx.java:4)
com.xxx.yyyy.PopUps$3.onFinish (PopUps.java:4)
android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage (CountDownTimer.java:127)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:236)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7876)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:656)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:967)
```

What I understand is that user.getEmail was null.

In all of the other activities, if I see that there is no user, I just direct to the Main activity. But here, it happened in the end of the deletion process and the whole data is deleted except to the user it self and it is problematic to direct them to the main activity, sign in again and go back to delete process.

How can I make sure that there will be a valid user when I get to this stage?

I also thought it might be due to the 7000 that I set which is used to make sure that the whole database is deleted before I end with user.delete.

Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to show the complete stack trace, as I'm not entirely sure right now where the error comes from in the code you shared. I also wouldn't depend on time-outs for whether a process has completed. Use callbacks for that instead.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen edited.

Comment: So it seems like you're calling `getCurrentUser().getEmail()` in  `com.xxx.yyyy.PopUps$3.onFinish`, but there's no current user at that point. Given what you're describing about the use-case, that seems to be correct. What do you still want to do when it reached `onFinish` and the user has already been deleted? Can't you just move to the next activity in that case?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen but there should be a user at this point until I delete it in task -> user.delete(). The thing is that when it reached that like there already wasn't a user.